# Travis builds for both ios and android via cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Is it possible to build android and ios applications with cordova on TravisCI with a single project and single travis.yml file?

I think I would just use `language: objective-c`, but how do I get the `android-sdk` and build tools installed?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, it can't be done.
iOS builds require Xcode. Xcode only runs on OS X machines.

Travis documentation for Android states, ["Android builds are not available on the OSX environment."](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/)

I'm investigating other options, looking into if its possible for one commit to generate two different related Travis builds. There was a Travis [feature request for dependent builds](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/249). It was on the roadmap for a while, then they dropped it with no plans to implement.